# I need a part of a field

Tags: sql

[image]Fieldname: DCCD

Characters in field: BAS **XXXX** 290 B2D explanation

I need the **XXXX** and want to place them in a seperate column.

- The first group (ex. BAS) are always 3 characters
- **The The XXXX can have 2, 3 or 4 characters**
- The third group have 2 or 3 karakters
- Between the groups there's always a space (spatie)

I got this code but it doesn't work.  Can someone please help me.  I don't know anything about this and I speak dutch :-)

```
LEFT(RIGHT([DCCD], (LEN([DCCD]) - SEARCH(" ", [DCCD]))), SEARCH(" ", RIGHT([DCCD], (LEN([DCCD]) - SEARCH(" ", [DCCD])))))
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Many products have their own string functions, like LEFT, LEN, etc)

Comment: I don't know.  Maybe you can see this on the picture i added?

Answer (score 1):

Use `CHARINDEX()` to find the `' '` in a string, start looking at position 5. Use `SUBSTRING()` to return from position 5.

```
substring(DCCD, 5, CHARINDEX(' ', DCCD, 5) -5)
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work.  I added a picture.